# Merge command from Git removes files

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bash

Git repository structure

[image]

I have used the following commands in Git Bash:

1. `git checkout develop_2`
2. `git merge develop_1`

Git was marked some files [deleted by us] and completed merge with conflicts.

What should I do to add new files from `develop_1` to `develop_2`?

Comment: Did you add the new files to git and commit them in develop_1?

Comment: Did you `stash` changes? Or added them? What exactly did you do with new added files?

Comment: New files were added (git add --all)

Comment: @Pavel did you commit the changes?

Comment: Yes, I did. We are developing a new functionality in develop_2 and regularly pick up changes from develop_1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the new files in `develop_1` and commit those changes.
`git add path/to/file`
`git commit -m "commit msg"`

Now, to bring those changes in `develop_2` branch, checkout to `develop_2` branch and merge `develop_1` branch onto `develop_2` branch.

`git checkout develop_2`
`git merge develop_1`

If any conflicts arise, resolve those conflicts. 
When you have resolved the conflicts, don't forget to add the files for which the conflicts came.

`git add path/to/file`

After doing this for all the conflict files, commit those conflict files again using:
`git commit -m "merge conflicts resolved"`

Those new files should be visible to you.

Comment: I did that as usual but got an unexpected result

Comment: Team explorer shows http://i.imgur.com/e9xumxT.png. ' git diff --name-status HEAD' doesn't see this files after merge

Comment: Please post the error log above. That might further help to solve the problem.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check again if the error comes.

Comment: Command 'git add path/to/file' doesn't work for this files because they automatically merged and deleted without conflicts.

Comment: Check if those files were deleted in some commit in `develop_1` branch.If those files were not present in develop_2 branch before, no coflicts would come and git would delete those files.